# What sort of functionality can I expect from exporting a Microsoft Access 2007 Database to a WSS 3.0 site?

Tags: ms-access, wss-3.0

I have a MS Access 2007 database and a WSS 3.0 site (neither of which I am very experienced in). The database is currently stored on a shared drive with users remoting in to work with it. In an effort to improve usability and performance, I want to host this db on my WSS 3.0 site. Is this feasible? I need to be able to access and edit data using forms, as well as run reports, all through the UI of the sharepoint site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can host an .accdb on a WSS 3.0 site, but users will need Access 2007 to open the database. See this article for basic info: http://office.com/redir.aspx?assetID=HA010131469.

If you want to host Access on Sharepoint and let folks who don't have Access use the database, you need Access 2010 and Sharepoint Server 2010: http://office.com/redir.aspx?assetID=HA010356866.